# Autodoc params?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm newbie using sphinx. It looks pretty good.
I have almost documented all my project using autodoc, but I want to change one behavior. Reading the documentation, I've seen this: [autodoc_member_order](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#configuration), and want to change to 'bysource' value, the point is, where am I supposed to put this value?

Thanks, and I apologize for my poor English.

Update: I'm using sphinx 0.6.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

put

```
autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'
```

at the bottom of the config file.

Of course you need version 1.0, as the docs you linked in the question mention:

> *Changed in version 1.0: Support for `'bysource'`.*

Comment: I've tried this, yet. Now at bottom of the conf.py file and it's not working. Maybe sphinx 0.6.6?

Comment: @slothy: Yeah, you need sphinx 1.0. See the end of the doc topic you linked yourself: *Changed in version 1.0: Support for 'bysource'.*

Comment: Ouch!...sorry I don't know what was thinking in...anyway, Is signal in the docs where to put extensions config values?

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Sphinx 1.0.7. The behavior is still alphabetic order after setting autodoc_member_order = 'bysource' in conf.py.